# Objects and Arrays in Javascript in React formatting

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have local data where I can access the first item using data{0}. Now I am moving over to a database and I get the data and create another object, but can no longer access the first item using data{0}.

I feel like I have a data nesting issue of some kind, but can't figure out how to format the data correctly. You can see in both cases I'm definitely getting data:

[console.log result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1n5Ds.png)

Local Data:

```
module.exports = [
  {
    date: "01/01/1802"
}
]
```

Remote Database Data:

```
    const databaseResult = web.lists
  .getByTitle("Database-Content")
  .items.get()
  .then((TimelineConent) => {
    TimelineConent.forEach(function (item, index) {
      items.push({
        date: item.date,
       
      });
    });

  });


this.setState({ items: items });
```

How can I format my database data to match the original local data format?

Comment: Maybe you should avoid using date formats, and instead store dates with `UNIX_TIMESTAMP()`

Comment: What's the output for console.log(items) ?

Comment: Output is in the screenshot, if you click the link..

Comment: Ugh . sorry in above I mean I can access the first item with  data[0]. but only in the local result. the database result data[0] is undefined.

Comment: Console.log: Array(0)
0: {date: "01/01/1802"}
1: {date: "01/01/1897"}
length: 2
__proto__: Array(0)

Answer (score 0):

Your data is stored as objects in an array, which means that you have to use data[0] instead of data{0} to get the first object from the array. Then you can access the values of the object using pointers.

```
let data = [{value: 2}]
console.log(data[0].value)
```

Outputs: `2`

I'm not sure whether you are asking about this or about preventing the nesting at data creation.

Comment: I'm sorry.. typo in the question. I can access the local result with data[0] but from the database data[0] is undefined.

Comment: It is difficult to tell what the problem is with this limited amount of code. Where are your console.log calls located in your code? Could it be that your setState has not finished setting the state (as it is an asynchronous operation)? Or that it sets the state before your request has finished? Console.log calls usually take precedence over setting the state when called in the same function.